# How to use functions and variables from different java class?

Tags: java

I have to design a PDF document.
Initially my job was to design only 1st page(named "Form.java")
So I created methods with parameters defining the font, no. of cols & rows,...

```
Function A(String staticdata, Font font, int colspan, int rowspan, int border)
```

It worked fine.. 
Now I have to design 2 additional pages using similar format and same methods.

So I created new java class(separate .java file) in which I put all the methods & declared all the variables..

Then I imported that .java file to the Form.java. But it gives me error that it cannot find function A(String staticdata, Font font, int colspan, int rowspan, int border)...
It also gives error to all variables in the methods...

How can i solve this.. I donot want to write the same methods for every page in the same project...
All files are in the same package and all classes are public...

Comment: Post the code and the actual error message. Without that this is not a real question. But you are really expected to be able to use multiple classes on your own.

Comment: if the above is your actual code you forgot the `public` modifier.

Answer (score 1):

It is basic in Object Oriented Programming. Create a `object` of any `class` and access it `public` methods.

So you just need to create the instance of the `Object` of `Form class` and you can able to call the method `A` by `instanceName.A(...)` like-

```
Form form = new Form();
form.A(...);
```

Note : if both class are in same package then you dont need to import.

Answer (score 1):

1) Verify the access specifier, If it is default .. then it can't accessible in other packages.
2) Verify that whether you have created the instance for the class and using that object you are calling the method A.

(or)

You can extend the parent class in other classes so that you can directly access the all inherited methods.

Answer (score -1):

If you create  an instance of class `separate` then the problem will be the visibility of the methods and properties.

In Java exist 4 visibilities types that controls who can see the method/property:

nothing - only the same package classes can see it

protected - same package and classes that extends this class

public - all

private - only in the same class

Comment: Zero evidence here that he has used `private`, and without that this is not an answer.

Comment: @EJP - sure he uses one of the four access types

Comment: @EJP according to the question he uses `default` see http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/library/ws-tip-mem-visibility.html

Comment: And he say he imports the class `separate` for what i think or he doesn't create a class instance (and do an unnecesary import) or he creates de class in other package and the methods aren't accesible